# Declare a variable with a column of type STRUCT in BIGQUERY

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table in bigquery with the following schema:

```
type:STRING,
resp:RECORD REPEATED {
    desc: STRING,
    age: INTEGER
}
```

I need to store all the data, just as it appears in the table, in a procedure.
This is how I declare the variable:

```
DECLARE catalogTip STRUCT<
    type STRING,
    resp STRUCT<
      desc STRING,
      age INT64
    >
  >;
```

This is the query that I want to store in the variable:

```
SET catalogTip = (SELECT * FROM CATALOG);
```

How do I have to declare the variable to be able to store this table?

Answer (score 2):

The catalogTip must be an array. The Select has to return an array and inside a struct. Is the `resp` a struct or an array of struct? Please choose the right example below.

```sql
DECLARE catalogTip ARRAY< STRUCT<
    type STRING,
    resp STRUCT<
      `desc` STRING,
      age INT64
    >
  > 
  >;
SET catalogTip =
(
With tbl as 
( Select type, struct("d" as `desc`, 27 as age) as resp 
from unnest(["T","t"]) as type)

select array_Agg(struct(type,resp)) from tbl )
```

Or this for an array of `resp` .

```sql
DECLARE catalogTip ARRAY< STRUCT<
    type STRING,
    resp array< STRUCT<
      `desc` STRING,
      age INT64
    > >
  > 
  >;
SET catalogTip =
(
With tbl as 
( Select type, [struct("d" as `desc`, 27 as age),("x",35)] as resp 
from unnest(["T","t"]) as type)

select array_Agg(struct(type,resp)) from tbl ) ;

# query the data:
Select * from unnest(catalogTip);
Select type, resp from unnest(catalogTip)
```

Comment: It is an array, with the second example it works, but I have a question, when executing the query in the variable it is saved with the following structure: f0_.type,f0_.resp.desc, f0_resp_age It is not possible to store it as in origin. I don't know if this can cause any problem?

Comment: And how can I access the type value? I get the following error when doing catalogTip.type:  Cannot access field tipologia on a value with type ARRAY<STRUCT<tipologia STRING, resp ARRAY<STRUCT<respDesc STRING, respPriority INT64>>>>

Answer (score 1):

To assign the result of the SELECT query to the catalogTip variable, the query should return only one row, which can be achieved by adding a LIMIT 1 clause to the SELECT statement:

```
SET catalogTip = (SELECT * FROM CATALOG LIMIT 1);
```

Alternatively, if the CATALOG table contains multiple rows and you want to store all of them in the catalogTip variable, you should declare catalogTip as an array of the given struct:

```
DECLARE catalogTip ARRAY<catalogTip STRUCT<
  type STRING,
  resp ARRAY<STRUCT<
    desc STRING,
    age INT64
  >>
>>;

SET catalogTip = (SELECT * FROM CATALOG);
```

Comment: The `select *` will throw the error "Query error: Scalar subquery cannot have more than one column". The query returns several elements. You need to add `FROM CATALOG LIMIT 1` or declare the `catalogTip ` as an array of the given struct.

Comment: Ah, like this: ```SET catalogTip = (SELECT * FROM CATALOG LIMIT 1);```